# Azure Blockchain Service - How to write and read to/from Transaction Node?

Tags: azure, azure-blockchain-service

We have created the Azure Blockchain Service to store a data securely. But we need a way to write and read the data from Transaction Node.

As of now, we can store the data in Transaction node using HTTP Post method as per this article

https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/azure-blockchain-service-quorum-tutorial-web3-truffle-develop/

But how to read the same data again from Transaction Node?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of weeks of study, I realized that we need to write smart contracts to read and write data to blockchain.

**Truffle Framework** provides a suite of tools for developing Ethereum smart contracts with the **Solidity** programming language.

**Web3.js** library, the main JavaScript library for interacting with the Ethereum Blockchain.

Thanks to Gregory McCubbin, a Ethereum Development Expert from [Dapp University](https://www.youtube.com/c/DappUniversity) who explains the Ethereum blockchain in a very effective manner.

https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-app-tutorial

The good news with azure blockchain service is that you can use **Azure Blockchain Development Kit for Ethereum VS Code extension** to attach to a consortium, create, connect, build, and deploy smart contracts on Ethereum blockchain ledgers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/connect-vscode